# How to resolve a mobx dependency issue when pushing a github action to github?

Tags: reactjs, github, cypress, github-actions

I'm trying to create a github action using cypress. My issue is that my application was installed with a mobx dependency issue. I've tried to resolve the dependency issue itself by downgrading mobx-react-form and mobx-react-form-devtools but then I ran into other dependency issue.

Is there a way to either resolve this dependency issue or force github to overlook it?

I know you can force an npm install by including "--force" or "--legacy-peer-deps" but that won't work here. Thanks in advance!

```html
Run cypress-io/github-action@v4
/usr/local/bin/npm ci
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: mobx-react-form-devtools@1.11.0
npm ERR! Found: mobx-react-form@2.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/mobx-react-form
npm ERR!   mobx-react-form@"2.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer mobx-react-form@"^1.x.x" from mobx-react-form-devtools@1.11.0
npm ERR! node_modules/mobx-react-form-devtools
npm ERR!   dev mobx-react-form-devtools@"1.11.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: mobx-react-form@1.39.1
npm ERR! node_modules/mobx-react-form
npm ERR!   peer mobx-react-form@"^1.x.x" from mobx-react-form-devtools@1.11.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/mobx-react-form-devtools
npm ERR!     dev mobx-react-form-devtools@"1.11.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/runner/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2022-07-19T19_22_13_749Z-debug-0.log
Error: The process '/usr/local/bin/npm' failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to bypass the dependency issue by adding an install-command option in the cypress run command:

```
    - name: Cypress run 
    uses: cypress-io/github-action@v4
    with:
      install-command: npm install --force
      browser: electron
      start: npm start
```